# Is there any reason that the Schwarzschild radius of a 5(+)-dimensional object would require different math?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, dimensional-analysis, event-horizon, singularities

$$R_g = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$$

It doesn't seem to me that the gravitational constant or speed of light particularly care how many dimensions there are in this context. Mass is mass whether it comes in vanilla or other. Am I missing any reasons to think that the Schwarzschild radius of a 5 (or 50?) dimensional object would follow the same math?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

General relativity in higher dimensions is speculative. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_Einstein_gravity

That being said, one idea that might give you pause is the origin of inverse-square laws: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law

Because we live in 3 space + 1 time dimension, electric and gravitational fields follow inverse square laws. But could possibly follow $\frac{1}{r^{n-1}}$ laws in n Dimensions.

If $F = \frac{GM}{r^{3}}$, for instance, then the gravitational constant G will have an extra dimension of length in it, so for the units to work out, you would have $R_{g}^{2} = \frac{GM}{c^{2}}$. In higher dimensions, the constant G could be different.